# Как запустить SQLite с программы на C++

Tags: c++, linux, sqlite, sqlite3

SQLite без проблем стартует из приложения на C++ (Linux) если это приложение запустить из консоли. Но когда приложение запускает автозапуск Линукса, SQLite не работает. "Can't open database"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

классическая проблема. Вы надеетесь, что рабочья директория (та директория, в которой ищутся файлы, если не указан полный путь) и место, где хранится бинарник всегда будут одни и теже. А это не так. Далеко не так. Правильный способ заключается в том, что бы хранить базу в заранее известном месте. Или записать путь к ней где нибудь в конфигах, которые опять же, хранятся в известном месте.

Конфиги можно хранить в каталоге /etc или его подкаталогах (если это хотя бы чучуть системное приложение). В противном случае лучше в домашнем каталоге в папке .config создать себе папку и хранить там всякие настройки (то есть, в каталоге `$HOME/.config`).

А свои разные файлы (базы к примеру), лучше хранить внутри `/var/local`

Если же это все не подходит, тогда создаете в каталоге /opt папку для своего приложениея и размещаете там файлы так, как Вам нравится. Это распространненая практика.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает